# The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

When I open a folder in my computer, I saw the message

"C:\Users\John Smith\Dropbox\myfolder1 is not accessible. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable."

Fortunately, all files in this folder are on my Dropbox account.
I copied this folder on Dropbox.com and made a duplicate folder names 'myfolder2.' Now this 'myfolder2' is accessible both online and on my local computer.

Then when should I do to 'myfolder1' folder?

(I'm using Windows 7 64-bit)

Comment: Back up critical data to an external storage device, then Run a chkdsk/r on the hard drive.

Comment: Provided all the files in `myfolder1` were all synced to DropBox, delete it.  If it contains sensitive information, utilize [`SDelete`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) to securely erase the files: `sdelete -p 3 -s .\myfolder1`

Comment: In my case, after running chkdsk <driver_letter>, it returned the files from that directory that are "incorrect" and I noticed that their name didn't comply with windows naming. After renaming them in my Linux partition, they were recognized just fine.

Answer (score -1):

try this

Click on Start→ go to Run→ Type cmd and press enter

“command prompt ” will be opened

you are having problem in c folder so enter the below commands

chkdsk /f c: → Press Enter

Good Luck

Comment: You usually need to Run As Administrator to run chkdsk, so from Start, you may need to go to Accessories, then right click on Command Prompt to Run As Administrator. I tend to think chkdsk c: /f is enough and /r is overkill and time consuming in many cases.